# Getting an Error: Could not find soffice binary

Tags: node.js, heroku, libreoffice

I am using libreoffice-convert to convert a docx file to pdf.It is workinjg fine in my local environment,but when deployed on heroku it is howing this error.I am uploading a docx file to s3 and then retrive that file and convert it into pdf by using libreoffice-convert library provided by npm.Since it uses libreoffice,for heroku i have added these buildpacks

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
2. https://github.com/BlueTeaLondon/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice-for-heroku-18.git
   and an aptfile containing these code [Aptfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzhdT.png)

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzhdT.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: There are several steps listed in the README of that LibreOffice buildpack. Instead of just linking to it, please include information about your app: the output of `heroku buildpacks` so we can see your actual buildpacks and the order they are in, the contents of your `Aptfile`. Do you see LibreOffice get installed at build time? Please read [ask].

Comment: Output for heroku buildpacks is  the following,

Comment: === pdf-convertor-jp Buildpack URLs
1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
2. https://github.com/BlueTeaLondon/heroku-buildpack-libreoffice-for-heroku-18.git
3. https://github.com/debitoor/heroku-buildpack-converter-fonts.git
4. heroku/nodejs

Comment: Aptfile Contains this libsm6
libice6
libxinerama1
libdbus-glib-1-2
libharfbuzz0b
libharfbuzz-icu0
libx11-xcb1
libxcb1

Comment: Got any answerr ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **libreoffice** on the instance where you are deploying your application.